# tcolorbox tcbline style

Tags: tcolorbox, line

I am using tcolorbox tcbline and it looks like dashed horizontal line. The color of this line can be set using colframe option:

[image]

But I need to cutomize the line itself (for example change the color, make it solid etc.) How to do so?

Code I am using to create tcolorbox environment:

```
\newtcolorbox{results}[1][]{%
    enhanced,breakable,
    colframe=topBlue,
    colback=white,
    arc=1mm,
    outer arc=1mm,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-4mm},
    boxed title style={size=small,colback=topBlue!10!white,boxsep=2.4mm,left=0mm,right=0mm},
    coltitle=topBlue!70!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\large,
    boxsep=5mm,
    left=0mm,
    right=0mm,
    before={\noindent},title=#1%
}
```

This is how I use it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{results}[Box title]
some text
\tcbline
more text
\tcbline
even more text
\end{results}
\end{document}
```

For example, it would be nice to have this tcbline:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just define the `segmentation style` that you need as is explained under `tcbline` definition in `tcolorbox` documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{results}[1][]{%
    enhanced,breakable,
    colframe=blue,
    colback=white,
    arc=1mm,
    outer arc=1mm,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=-4mm},
    boxed title style={size=small,colback=blue!10!white,boxsep=2.4mm,left=0mm,right=0mm},
    coltitle=blue!70!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\large,    
    boxsep=5mm,
    left=0mm,
    right=0mm,
    before={\noindent},
    segmentation style={solid, red!30},
    title=#1%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{results}[Box title]
some text
\tcbline
more text
\tcbline
even more text
\end{results}
\end{document}
```

[image]